# google guice @Inject giving null while doing DI @Autowired in spring

Tags: spring, spring-boot, dependency-injection, playframework, guice

I am working in the spring framework and microservice arch. I have one class like `MainClass.java` in that I am injecting `LibraryClass.java` using `@AutoWired`. `LibraryClass.java` class is present inside `data-lib.jar`

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import com.data.LibraryClass;

public class MainClass {

    @Autowired
    LibraryClass libraryClass;

    String value = libraryClass.getData();
}
```

Inside `data-lib.jar` dependency jar `LibraryClass.java` file look like this and I am injecting `OtherLibraryClass.java` using google guice DI `@Inject`. `OtherLibraryClass.java` class also present inside `data-lib.jar`

```
package com.data;
import com.google.inject.Inject;

public class LibraryClass {

     @Inject
     OtherLibraryClass otherLibraryClass;

     public String getData() {
          return  otherLibraryClass.getValue(); // throwing null pointer exception      
     }

}
```

While calling `getData()` method from `MainClass.java` it is throwing null pointer exception. it is looking like `OtherLibraryClass.java` instance is not automatically created by Guice. If it is created by Guice then automatically Inject all dependency.

I don't want to change anything inside `data-lib.jar`.I can change in `MainClass.java` so that problem will resolve. Is there any way to work properly without any exception.

**Note :** `data-lib.jar` was build in play framework. that's why I don't want to change inside the dependency jar. If we call `getData()` method from other play framework serv it is working fine. Only while calling from spring frameworks serv I am facing this prob

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Annotate your MainClass with @Component for DI to work.

Comment: Ofcourse it is going to be `null`. Spring doesn't understand Guice's `@Inject` so it will be ignored.

Comment: Ya i understood .. but i want to know .. is there any way to make around

Comment: Don't use Guice's `@Inject`. Use `@javax.inject.Inject` instead. Both Guice and Spring know it.

Comment: After using `@javax.inject.Inject`  it is working fine my problem resolved .. As @Olivier said Both spring and Guice knowns `@javax.inject.Inject` .. Thanks for helping me out @Olivier